# How to run tests by multiple categories using command line in Gradle?

Tags: testing, gradle, junit, categories

I have several tests and each of them is marked with one or more categories listed below

```
@Category(SmokeTest.class)
@Category(RegressionTest.class)
@Category(StressTest.class)
```

How can I run tests by multiple categories? For example what I have to write in command line to run tests marked category "SmokeTest" and "StressTest"?

In build.gradle I have to add:

```
test {
    useJUnit() {
        if (project.hasProperty("cat"))
            includeCategories "com.path.to.categories.interfaces.folder.$cat"
    }
}
```

And then enter the following command in terminal:

```
./gradle clean test -Pcat=SmokeTest,StressTest
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Guessing you could do

```
def cats = project.property('cat').split(',').collect {
   "com.path.to.categories.interfaces.folder.$it"
} 
includeCategories cats
```

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't work this option.

Comment: Not helpful feedback, what's the error message?

Answer (score 0):

```
you could add this to your gradle file:
test {
    useJUnit {
        if (project.hasProperty("cat"))
            includeCategories = (project.property('cat').split(',').collect 
             {
                "com.philips.dtc.category.$it".toString()
             }) as List
    }
}
```

command: gradle clean test -Pcat=SmokeTest,StressTest